# php wont echo results from inner join query

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join

I've looked around the site for similar problems with solutions and non seem to fix the problem I have. I have two tables; "friendlist" and "users". I'm trying to use the "FriendID" from "friendlist" to retrieve information from the "users" table. Everything works fine up until the `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){}` loop then nothing else prints.

My code is as follows:

```
$query = "SELECT friendlist.FriendID, users.Name, users.Surname, users.Picture 
                FROM friendlist            
                INNER JOIN users
                ON friendlist.FriendID = users.Id
                WHERE friendlist.UserId ='".$id."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

if(!$result){
    echo "<br/><h4>You currently do not have any friends. Please click the Find Friends button to find a friend</h4>";
}else{
    echo "<center><br/>Here is a list of all your friends:<br/>";
    echo "<table>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>Pro Pic: <img style='width:200px; height:200px' alt='No Profile Picture' src='uploads/" .$row['Picture']. "' /></td>";
        echo "<td>Name :" .$row['Name']. "</td>";
        echo "<td>Surname :" .$row['Surname']. "</td>";
        echo "<td><form method='post' action='viewFriend.php'>";
        echo     "<input type='hidden' name='friendId' value='".$row['FriendID']."'/>";
        echo     "<input type='submit' name='View' value='View Profile'/>";
        echo "</form></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table></center>";
}
```

Nothing is displayed on the browser. Only the level 4 heading text: "Here is a list of all your friends" shows. But after that its empty space.
I've checked the sql query on mySql and it works perfectly fine. I have no idea what's wrong. Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: echo mysqli_num_rows($result); and check how many rows are their?

Comment: You're most likely prone to SQL injection and need to fix this ASAP unless you want anyone to be able to show all users in the entire system. Use prepared statements and bind variables. Magically changing `mysql_` to `mysqli_` does not fix this.

Comment: Or go run your query first in phpmyadmin to check of they have contents.

Comment: @SureshKamrushi the result is 0! But I dont understand how because as Christian Mark suggested I ran the query on phpmyadmin and it returned 2 rows of results.

Comment: Are you sure you are connected on the right database ? And well connected to it ? Have you checked for php errors ?

Comment: This code looks ok to me.

Comment: @h2ooooooo I've tried using prepared statements and bind variables but they wouldn't work properly so I kind of gave up on them. using mysqli seemed much more simple. p.s I've only started working with php and mysql so my understanding of how it all works is at a low level

Comment: @OlivierH Yeah I'm 100% sure I've connected to the right database. I've used the connection method for inserting, adding, updating and even selecting. I just have a problem now when I want to join tables...

Comment: @user1726443 How did you test your query ? You `echo $query;` and then copy/paste the output into phpmyadmin ? Are you ABSOLUTELY SURE that the content of `$query` is a valid query which gives you results when you execute it directly ?

Comment: @OlivierH what I initially did was try out the query in phpadmin first then copy/paste it to my php code. But I tried what you said and the query works in phpadmin! It's so weird, I don't understand.

Comment: use fetch_assoc instead.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on your SQL Query.
You did not put friendlist.UserId on the select part.
That's why the where clause do not see where to compare it.

```
 $query = "SELECT friendlist.FriendID, users.Name, users.Surname, users.Picture 
                    FROM friendlist            
                    INNER JOIN users
                    ON friendlist.FriendID = users.Id
                    WHERE friendlist.UserId ='".$id."'";
```

Comment: I tried that but it didnt work :( I don't think it makes sense to select friendlist.UserId if I'm trying to use it as a search criteria... if you know what I mean

Comment: I just realised what my mistake was, so stupid!! >__< $id didn't have a set value yet. In the beginning of the script when i set my session : 
`session_start();
$id = $_SESSION['id'];`
I thought I had already assigned $id with the value. I had to assign it again `$id = $_SESSION` (not sure why tho) and now it works.

Thanks for your suggestions and sorry for the inconvenience... P.S Do I need to delete the question seeing as the code wasn't the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct but you miss the declaration of $id variable only.
Use like below.

```
//initialize  the $id as.

$id = $_REQUEST['id'];

    $query = "SELECT friendlist.FriendID, users.Name, users.Surname, users.Picture 
                    FROM friendlist            
                    INNER JOIN users
                    ON friendlist.FriendID = users.Id
                    WHERE friendlist.UserId ='".$id."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

    if(!$result){
        echo "<br/><h4>You currently do not have any friends. Please click the Find Friends button to find a friend</h4>";
    }else{
        echo "<center><br/>Here is a list of all your friends:<br/>";
        echo "<table>";
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>Pro Pic: <img style='width:200px; height:200px' alt='No Profile Picture' src='uploads/" .$row['Picture']. "' /></td>";
            echo "<td>Name :" .$row['Name']. "</td>";
            echo "<td>Surname :" .$row['Surname']. "</td>";
            echo "<td><form method='post' action='viewFriend.php'>";
            echo     "<input type='hidden' name='friendId' value='".$row['FriendID']."'/>";
            echo     "<input type='submit' name='View' value='View Profile'/>";
            echo "</form></td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table></center>";
    }
```